# Где в базе данных лежат фотографии

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, когда прикрепляешь фотографии к записи, где в БД можно найти эту ссылку?

Comment: Быстрее, а главное полезней самому поискать в базе и разобраться как формируется ссылка, который в базе нет.

Comment: Тебе для чего и где будешь использовать это? В зависимости от ответа, можем предложить решение. Если тебе нужен список - это одно, если вывести ссылку внутри поста или карточки товара (для скачивания) - это другое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные об изображении записи хранятся в произвольном поле с ключом `_thumbnail_id`. Искать соответственно в таблице `wp_postmeta`. Ну а зная id изображения уже можно найти его ссылку в таблице `wp_posts`. Медиафайлы в `WordPress` - это посты с типом `attachment`.

Comment: В `wp_posts` нет никаких ссылок. Есть только слаг. Причем это будет слаг страницы аттачмента.

Comment: Столбец `guid` содержит ссылку непосредственно на файл

Comment: Да, ты прав (я совсем забыл про guid). Но это поле ненадёжно, тк в некоторых случаях может не соответствовать реальностям.